# Cannot get gorilla session.Value by key

Tags: session, go, gorilla

The problem is, cannot get value from session.Value in another file in the same package

In the controllers.go file

```
func (c *AuthenticationControllers) AdminLogin() http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")

          //AUTHENTICATION

        if answer {
            w.Write([]byte("Successful Authenticated!"))

            //1* Create Session

            session, _ := store.Get(r, "session") //SESSION START

            ///Here I've setted true
            session.Values["authenticated"] = true//Successful Authenticated

            sessionToken, _ := uuid.NewV4() //Generate session token

            session.Values["userid"] = sessionToken.String()

            session.Save(r, w)


            //Redirect
            http.Redirect(w, r, "/admin/application", 302)
        } else {
            //http.Redirect(w, r, "/login", 302)

            http.Error(w, http.StatusText(http.StatusForbidden), http.StatusForbidden)
        }

    }
}
```

IN middleware.go file in the same package

```
 func (m *AuthenticationMiddleWares) RequiresLogin(handler http.HandlerFunc) http.HandlerFunc {
    return func(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
        session, _ := store.Get(r, "session") //!!!

        if auth, ok := session.Values["authenticated"].(bool); !ok || !auth {
            http.Error(w, "Forbidden", http.StatusForbidden)
            return
        }

        handler(w, r)
    }
}


 session.Values["authenticated"] //has nil value, but has to be true after authentification in order to get you access to the route
router.HandleFunc("/admin/applications", authMiddle.RequiresLogin(authContrl.Application()))
```

What I have done wrong? Why session.Values["authenticated"] returns "nil"

Answer (score 0):

`session, _ := store.Get(r, "session") //SESSION START`, your session depends on the request `r`, which is a pointer that is created by the package that calls your controller. If you are calling `session` from another file, you need to ensure, that it is the same request that is passed into `store.Get()`. That could be the reason.

Comment: how i can get the request from controllers handlers

Comment: that is difficult without actually calling the controller. So the function which needs this session, can be called either within the controller or in the middleware. You can do this in multiple ways but for that you need to tell me where this new file is and what you want it to do.

Comment: structure of my authentication api is like:
-----Authentication API
-services.go
-controllers.go
-middleware.go

-------
after /login, I set value of ["authenticated"] = true, in order to check if user authenticated to  get him access to the route:/admin/application

Comment: have you checked if client is setting the cookie from response you get from `login` in all subsequent requests?

Comment: I have checked session, _ := store.Get(r, "session") in the middleware, so it returns empty map, it means that it does not see  stored values 
But I have saved it with Save() method in the login. It has confused me

Comment: check at the client side code if cookie is read from response, and set into new request. this is how cookie-session management works. All that `store.Get` does is read from a database. For that it needs the key under which session is stored. That key is the cookie.